# "mrp2_gazebo.launch" from mrp2_gazebo package error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on [mrp2_navigation/Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/mrp2_navigation/Tutorials/Navigate%20in%20Simulation/Navigate%20with%20a%20known%20map) and when i try to run the command

```
roslaunch mrp2_gazebo mrp2_gazebo.launch
```

from "Explore surrounding areas and make a map" it gives the error

```
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/opt/ros/indigo/share/mrp2_description/launch/description.launch'
```

because it makes a call to description.launch file from mrp2_description package but it doesn't exist.

Hope you fix this problem so people can complete the tutorial successfully.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251704/%22mrp2_gazebo.launch%22-from-mrp2_gazebo-package-error/) by [Reki10](https://answers.ros.org/users/29008/reki10/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like you skipped to install mrp2_description package.

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-mrp2-description
```

---

Originally posted by [orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26641/orhan/) with karma: 73 on 2017-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alexander Petrov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3939/alexander-petrov/) on 2017-11-04**:
I also have such a problem and I see that ros-indigo-mrp2-description have already been installed.

**Comment by [Alexander Petrov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3939/alexander-petrov/) on 2017-11-04**:
It looks like that file is here - https://github.com/milvusrobotics/mrp2_common/tree/indigo-devel/mrp2_description/launch